# How to force a Airflow Task to restart at the new scheduling date?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have this simple Airflow DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
with DAG("Second Dag", 
        start_date=datetime(2022,1,1), 
        schedule_interval="0 5 * * *", 
        catchup=False,
        max_active_runs=1
        ) as dag:

    task_a = BashOperator(
        task_id="ToRepeat",
        bash_command="cd /home/xdf/local/ && (env/bin/python workflow/test1.py)",
        retries =1,
    )
```

The task takes a variable amount of time between one run and the other, and I don't have any guarantee that it will be finished within the 5 A.M of the next day.
If the task is still running when a new task is scheduled to start, I need to kill the old one before it starts running.

How can I design Airflow DAG to automatically kill the old task if it's still running when a new task is scheduled to start?

More details:
I am looking for something dynamic. The old DAG should be killed only when the new DAG is starting. If, for any reason, the new DAG does not start for one week, then old DAG should be able to run for an entire week. That's why using a timeout is sub-optimal

Comment: Set dagrun_timeout?

Answer (score 2):

You should set [`dagrun_timeout`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f91f1ca9773fce258f02a6bc3c11d16ac029467b/airflow/models/dag.py#L237) for your DAG.

```
dagrun_timeout: specify how long a DagRun should be up before
timing out / failing, so that new DagRuns can be created. The timeout
is only enforced for scheduled DagRuns.
```

Since your DAG runs daily you can set 24 hours for timeout.

```
with DAG("Second Dag", 
        start_date=datetime(2022,1,1), 
        schedule_interval="0 5 * * *", 
        catchup=False,
        max_active_runs=1
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=24)
        ) as dag:
```

If you want to set timeout on a specific task in your DAG you should use [`execution_timeout`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/833087f4f9e86ee063d6a754593d80e9e5cd4100/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L557) on your operator.

`execution_timeout: max time allowed for the execution of this task instance, if it goes beyond it will raise and fail`

Example:

```
MyOperator(task_id='task', execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=24))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. However I was looking for something more dynamics. I would like the timeout to depend on when the new task is being triggered

Comment: Hi Elias, I think there was a misunderstanding. If it use a task specific timeout, I still have to set before starting the DAG when a specific tasks is going to terminate (relative to one is being called). However I would like to able to set it so that it fails only when the new DAG is starting

Comment: You have max_active_runs=1 a new dag can not start until the previous one completed.

Comment: That's right. I will remove it, but still the old task will be killed only when the timeout is reached and independently of the new DAG

Comment: I dont think the functionality you are after exist. You can set timeouts but you can not terminate dagrun from another dagrun. The best you can do is change the statuses but this is not really termination.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are looking for a dynamic solution; you can take help of Airflow [DAGRun APIs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/DAGRun) and Xcoms; you can push your current dag run_id to Xcom and for subsequent runs you can pull this Xcom to consume with airflow API to check and kill the dag run with that run_id.

check_previous_dag_run_id >> kill_previous_dag_run >> push_current_run_id >> your_main_task

and your API call task should be something like

```
...
kill_previous_dag_run = BashOperator(
    task_id="kill_previous_dag_run",
    bash_command="curl -X 'DELETE' \
        'http://<<your_webserver_dns>>/api/v1/dags/<<your_dag_name>>/dagRuns/<<url_encoded_run_id>>' \
        -H 'accept: */*' --user <<api_username>>:<<api_user_password>>",
    dag=dag
)
...
```